# Back button in Android and android:noHistory="true"

Tags: android, back-button, activity-finish

I have implement an application with many screens, an used `android:noHistory="true"` for exiting from any of the screen... I have *EXIT* `Button` on all the Screens in my application..

But i have faced a problem while processing the Application, In table if the user clicks on the *BACK* `Button` the application ends...

[image: Default Tablet Buttton in TABLET]

Now i'm looking for an `AlertDialog` while the User clicks on the Default Back `Button`..

Suggest me any solution for the problem.

After Some Suggestion i tried this, and this also Not Worked..

The Code which i tried is..

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you Sure want to close the Application..?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setTitle("EXIT")
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

Comment: Omit super.onBackPressed();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override onBackPressed of the activity to do whatever you want (like pop up a dialog).

Comment: Don't call super.onBackPressed.  That function ends the activity.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

Ovrride `onbackpressed` on your activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    //ADD ALERT DIALOG HERE

}
```

Comment: Don't call super, that will cause it to finish the activity.  Just override it.